# Cannot authenticate using API Key with NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nlog

I cannot get NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch to connect to a local ElasticSearch instance using an APIKey.

My `nlog.config` has the following:

```xml
    <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="elasticSearch" flushTimeout ="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" uri="https://dev.myinstance.com:9200" 
              includeAllProperties="true" 
              apiKey="MUhUUG1ZQUJFWE5GNDlPT3J5S3c123456783JRQS1CM1JtQVJzUWppdw=="
              apiKeyId="1HTPmYABEXNF49OOryKw"
              documentType=""
              index="test-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
              name="test">
      </target>
    </target>
```

The API Key has been verified using curl:

```
curl --insecure -H "Authorization: ApiKey MUhUUG1ZQUJFWE5GNDlPT3J5S3c123456783JRQS1CM1JtQVJzUWppdw==" https://dev.myinstance.com:9200/_security/api_key?pretty
{
  "api_keys" : [
    {
      "id" : "1HTPmYABEXNF49OOryKw",
      "name" : "test_import",
      "creation" : 1651847966642,
      "invalidated" : false,
      "username" : "elastic",
      "realm" : "reserved",
      "metadata" : { }
    }
  ]
}
```

Yet, nlog cannot auth:

```
Exception: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Failed to ping the specified node. Call: Status code 401 from: HEAD
---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Failed to ping the specified node. 
---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Could not authenticate with the specified node. Try verifying your credentials or check your Shield configuration. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I've tried adding `requireAuth` to the `nlog.config` with no luck.

Comment: This looks like it could be a version issue. We using Elastic 8.1, while it looks like the .net package that this depends on only supports 7.

Comment: Maybe configure `disablePing="true"`. See also https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the NLog version
in version 4 I could with this config connect and add log
I think you should use  username and password instead of Apikey

```
   includeAllProperties="true"
   documentType=""
   requireAuth ="true"
   username ="xxxxxx"
   password ="xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter some issue with this.
In my case the issue was connected with improper format of the authorization header.

I am using [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) so all my configuration is located in `appsettings.json`
In the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-api-authentication.html) header is formatted:
`Authorization: ApiKey ...`

but if you are using [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) separation sign is `=`
`Authorization=ApiKey ...`